# Draw numbers from Bernoulli distribution using scipy

Tags: scipy, bernoulli-probability

How can I draw numbers from a Bernoulli distribution using `scipy` efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the fact that the Bernoulli distribution is a special case of the Binomial distribution with `n=1`.

Example:

```
import scipy as sp
p = 0.2
sp.random.binomial(1, p)
```